# DIOS Drupal SDK ARC problems in new Xcode?

Tags: ios, drupal, xcode4, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to run the example program for Drupal iOS SDK as downloaded here https://github.com/workhabitinc/drupal-ios-sdk-example

But, I can't build the project because of the ARC problems as in the screenshot below.

[image]

How can I change the settings or code to make it compile?

Comment: i got the same problem today.. then i downloaded the latest drupal in git .. there was no errors but drupal taking very much time to load..

Comment: Did refractor not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue - I resolved it by disabling ARC partially. I used ARC for all my code and disabled it for all downloaded stuff.

See [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

This is only a temporary fix, but I guess you just want to run it to see it in action so it should be feasible.